# Import NFTs data from Metamask

Tags: metamask, wallets, erc-721, nft

Goal: Sign in to the server with Metamask (done), import information to the server about NFTs from a wallet (not done) to our platform (trading platform similar to Opensea).
Problem: Metamask uses OpenSea to store NFT data
[Docs ref](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058238591-NFT-tokens-in-MetaMask-wallet)

Possible solutions:

1. List NFTs on Opensea and query Opensea API (if possible) to fetch NFTs data;
2. Manually transfer NFT (ERC721) ownership from the wallet to our server and then sell it.

Is this correct or there is a better approach? Links to tutorials/articles will be very helpful too.